# Не перенаправляется вывод из cmd в файл

Tags: python, windows, cmd, rabbitmq

Приветсвую, всех) Моя программа из двух файлов: emit_log.py - отправитель сообщений и приёмник - receive_logs.py. Если запустить приёмник в консоли (`python receive_logs.py`), то всё сообщения принимаются и выводятся на экран нормально. При попытке перенаправить вывод в файл в cmd Windows ничего не происходит(`python receive_logs.py > logs_from_rabbit.log`)... А точнее создаётся лишь файл logs_from_rabbit.log, но он пуст! Подскажите, в чём ошибка? В Windows ведь также, как и в Linux перенаправление с помощью оператора >...

Вот сами коды в файлах:
emit_log.py:

```
import pika
import sys


message = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) or "info: Hello World!"
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs', exchange_type='fanout')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='logs', routing_key='', body=message)
print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)
connection.close()
```

receive_logs.py:

```
import pika


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] %r" % body)


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs', exchange_type='fanout')
result = channel.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue
channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs', queue=queue_name)
print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.basic_consume(
    queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()
```

Это третий тутор по RabbitMQ, если кому интересно: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html

Comment: Вы просматриваете файл после окончания работы программы или во время её работы?

Comment: Ух ты как интересно) Получается, нужно обязательно завершать выполнение скрипта python для того, чтобы в файл что-либо записалось?

Comment: Читайте мой ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваша программа не завершает работу, в файле не будет ничего отображено, т.к. при использовании `>` он открывается на запись и не закрывается до тех пор, пока программа не вернёт управление ОС. А пока файл не закрыт, другие программы (в т.ч. и те, с помощью которых Вы можете просматривать файл) получают информацию о том состоянии файла, в котором он находился ДО того, как был открыт в `cmd`. Все изменения в нём отобразятся только после закрытия, т.е. после завершения работы Вашей программы.

Хороший способ писать логи в файлы – сделать группу функций, а лучше класс, отвечающий за вывод логов. И в методах этого класса уже определять конкретный способ вывода (будь то в консоль, в файл, в сеть или куда-либо ещё). Это поможет решить массу проблем, например:

1. Вы сможете закрывать файл после каждой записи, чтобы всегда иметь возможность читать из файла актуальную информацию
2. Чтобы изменить способ логгирования, нужно изменить только один метод, а не множество частей кода, где это логгирование используется

Вот пример использования такого класса в Вашем случае:

```py
import pika

""" Класс лучше объявить в отдельном модуле и подключить импортом, здесь он просто для краткости объявлен так"""
class Logger:
    def log(self, log_string):
        file = open("logs_from_rabbit.log", 'w')
        file.write(log_string)
        file.close()

logger = Logger()

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    logger.log(" [x] %r" % body) # Заменяем все print на logger.log()


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs', exchange_type='fanout')
result = channel.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue
channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs', queue=queue_name)
logger.log(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.basic_consume(
    queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()
```

В итоге будем получать актуальную информацию при каждом открытии файла. Здесь налицо первое из описанных мной преимуществ. А теперь, если вдруг Вы захотите выводить лог в консоль, нужно будет всего лишь сделать так:

```py
import pika

class Logger:
    def log(self, log_string):
        print(log_string) # Поменяли код в только одном месте!

logger = Logger()

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    logger.log(" [x] %r" % body)


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs', exchange_type='fanout')
result = channel.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue
channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs', queue=queue_name)
logger.log(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.basic_consume(
    queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()
```

Здесь явно видно второе из описанных преимуществ. Чтобы ещё отчётливее понять его, представьте, если бы логгирование велось не из двух мест программы, а из двухсот. Изменить 2-3 строки в разы легче, чем двести раз по 2-3.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример, пригодится.

Comment: @Chudvan Конечно, минутку

Comment: @Chudvan Готово, обратите внимание на комментарии в коде